# How to generate a report like invoice from a template offline in flutter or dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

I would like to generate an invoice from template in flutter from a pre-designed template in flutter offline.

I found some reporting services like Telerik, Syncfusion but they don't support flutter in offline mode. You need to call external report engine API which is not applicable in my case because our app is working completely offline.

So, please if there are any common library to achieve this please let me know.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf might be worth looking into.